# IN Function is not working properly with JOINS

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT mp.institute_id,
    mp.category_id,
    mp.mapp_branch_id,
    mp.mapp_product_id
FROM mapping_with_products mp
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON cat.id = mp.category_id
WHERE mp.mapp_product_id IN ( 5 ,12 ,34 ,90 ,123 )
ORDER BY mp.category_id DESC
```

`IN` is not working with JOINS. Query is executed but data is not displayed. I have already checked. Data is mapped as given ID.

Comment: I assure you it's working as expected. Share your sample data for any of `mapp_product_id's` from your `IN` clause from both tables. Right now it seems like no rows satisfy your conditions.

Comment: Can you provide sample data as text to back up your contention.

Comment: Don't roll back to your bad-formatted question please.

Comment: Can you provide mapped data?

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with the IN function, Just run the query without the Where clause and check are you getting the below values for mp.mapp_product_id.
5 ,12 ,34 ,90 ,123